# Why is Route 53 forwarding traffic using the wildcard rule instead of the most specific one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a private hosted zone on Route 53 for the domain name:

```
dev.example.com
```

There's one CNAME record that routes traffic to an Elastic Load Balancer:

```
*.dev.example.com.  CNAME  xyz.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I tried adding the following record:

```
sftp.dev.example.com.  A  10.0.11.12
```

but traffic is always going through the load balancer.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most specific record is returned first - traffic shouldn't be going through your load balancer when you look up `sftp.dev.example.com`.

So the issue isn't with route53. My guess is that you have `sftp.dev.example.com` cached somewhere as the load balancer's IP address.

Comment: I don't think it's cached anywhere. I created additional record sets with random names and they all end up going through the ELB. How can I debug this? How can I make sure that "*.dev.example.com" is not cached?